# How to change text color in spinner?

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, android-studio

i changed the theme of my dialog so that the title background would change , what happened is that the spinner background changed also to black and the items text color is black also , with cause a problem .

here is my style.xml code :

```
<style name="question_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item      
name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/question_dialog_title</item>
</style>

<style name="question_dialog_title" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">#161616</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#e1e1e1</item>
</style>
```

and here is the picture of the dialog: 
http://s32.postimg.org/ixt6rm02d/13128639_1306213616061269_1278459383_o.jpg

Help me please:))

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom XML file for your spinner item.

spinner_item.xml:

Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"  
android:textColor="#FF0000"         
android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

Now pass this xml to the adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

You don't need to set the drop down resource. It will take spinner_item.xml only to show your items in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Creat a item xml like
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left" 
android:textColor="#FF0000"
android:padding="5dip"/>
```

Then, use adapter to adap to the item created.